# Is there a minimum term length required for features in Sklearn TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas, tfidfvectorizer

I have a pandas dataframe with sentences that I'm trying to calculate Tfidf on:

```
df['sentence'] = ['buy donuts', 'buy donuts', 'buy donuts', 'buy donuts', 'buy donuts', 'buy donuts', 'buy donuts', 'buy donuts', 'buy donuts', 'buy donuts', 'purchase donuts', 'purchase donuts', 'purchase donuts', 'purchase donuts', 'purchase donuts', 'buy donut', 'buy a donut', 'buy 2 donuts', 'buy 2 donuts', 'buy 2 donuts', 'buy 12 donuts', 'buy 12 donuts', 'buy 12 donuts', 'purchase 2 donuts', 'purchase 12 donuts', 'i want to buy 2 donuts', 'i want to buy 12 donuts', 'i want to buy donuts', 'i want to buy some donuts', 'buy some donuts', 'buy two donuts', 'buy two donuts', 'buy two donuts', 'buy twelve donuts', 'buy twelve donuts', 'buy twelve donuts', 'purchase two donuts', 'purchase twelve donuts', 'i want to buy two donuts', 'i want to buy twelve donuts']
```

I first lemmatize these sentences (code below) and then feed the lemmatized list to sklearn's tfidfvectorizer.

However, I'm noticing a weird anomaly where it is not including some of the terms as features, even though min_df and max_df are set to their default value to include all terms. When I run get_feature_names(), every term is listed as a feature except 'i', 'a', and '2':

```
['12', 'buy', 'donut', 'purchase', 'some', 'to', 'twelve', 'two', 'want']
```

I am not removing stopwords. For my purposes, "2" is very distinguishing, is there a minimum term length for features in tfidfvectorizer? How can I get these terms included as features?

```
nlp = spacy.load("en", disable=['ner'])
vect = TfidfVectorizer(binary=True)

## Load in data
df = pd.read_csv('buy donuts.csv', encoding='utf-8')
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()

## Normalize sentences
df['sentence'] = df['sentence'].str.replace(r"[^\w\s']", '').str.lower().str.strip().replace('', np.nan)

df = df.dropna(subset=['unit name', 'sentence'])

## Get lemmas for tfidf
def lemmas(x):
    docs = nlp(x)
    sents_lemma = [token.lemma_ for token in docs]
    return ' '.join(sents_lemma)

df['lemmas'] = df.index.map(df['sentence'].apply(lemmas))

## Get tfidf and calculate scores
tfidf = vect.fit_transform(df.lemmas.values.tolist())
scores = ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A).mean(axis=0)

print(vect.get_feature_names())
```

Comment: This is an interesting question.  In my case I would want to exclude one letter tokens because they would be noise, however it really depends upon the corpus

Answer (score 0):

Check out the regular expression used by your TfidfVectorizer which you do not explicitly set.  This can be accessed (or changed) with the `token_pattern` parameter.

It is `(?u)\b\w\w+\b` which you can see would prevent `2` or `I` from being recognized.

I am not sure which regex is most appropriate for your use case, perhaps you play around with it a little.  However the following would capture the case of `buy 2 donut`

```
(?u)\b\w+\b
```

So anyway to answer the general question, you could craft your `token_pattern` in such a way to enforce a minimum length (or even a maximum length) I suppose.